# How to create a file that is recognized as svg not xml

Tags: xml, svg, nsdata, nsfilemanager, finder

I'm writing a program that generates .svg file from CGPoint (It draws a red circle at the coordinates of the CGPoint).

Here is the code to generate the xml code :

```
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(250.0, 250.0);
float width = 500.0;
float height = 500.0;

NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[str setString:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"];
[str appendString:@"<!DOCTYPE svg>"];
[str appendString:@"<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\""];
[str appendString:@" version=\"1.1\""];
[str appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" width=\"%f\"", width]];
[str appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" height=\"%f\">", height]];
[str appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<circle cx=\"%f\" cy=\"%f\" r=\"10\" fill=\"red\"/>", myPoint.x, myPoint.y]];
[str appendString:@"</svg>"];
```

Here is the code to create the file :

```
NSData *imageData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableString *fileName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[fileName setString:@"/myImage.svg"];

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[myDirectoryURL path] stringByAppendingString:fileName]];

[fileManager createFileAtPath:[fileURL path] contents:imageData attributes:nil];
```

Everything works perfectly. The file is created in the right directory. But the problem is that the FINDER recognize it as a xml file not a svg file.

Question : Is there a way to indicate in the xml file or to the NSFileManager that I'm creating a svg file not an xml one ?

Comment: Does your Finder recognize other .svg files as svg files and not "classic" xml files?

Comment: Larme, you're right ! It's not a problem in my code. I just forgot to select an application to open this type of file. In order to solve the problem, I selected the svg file generated. Hit cmd+I. Select the application in "Open with :" (in my case Firefox). And then hit the button "Modify All..." to apply this selection to all the files that have the .svg extension. Thanks !